# Add user group to slack channel depending on name

Tags: jira, slack, zapier, opsgenie, responders

Im disappointed with Jira Service Managements inability to automatically create a slack channel with responders added when we create an incident. (It can be done manually from within the incident)

I have managed to have the channel create using JIRA automation (and also works with Zapier) but again there is no way to pick up all of the responders - It will pick up reporter, assignee and one responder.

Im thinking I can create user groups, that match our JSM/Opsgenie responder groups, in slack and have that user group added to the channel with a trigger from the channel name (or a automated comment in the slack channel)

Has anyone come across something like this, or an alternative way, And can anyone advise how I can solve this.